# Can one transit a friend's money through one's account cause any issue (e.g., triggering some tax event)?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, european-union

For convenience and/or avoiding some banking fees, one may want to transit a friend's money through one's account. E.g. Alice's bank account in France -> Bob's bank account in France -> Bob's bank account in the  US -> Alice's bank account in the US.

Can that cause any issue (e.g., triggering some tax event)?

Assumptions:

- Neither Alice nor Bob is a scammer.
- Ignore any potential restrictions/regulations on moving money between countries.

Comment: What does Bob get for doing this?

Comment: @quid Nothing~~

Comment: What's the size of the transfer?

Comment: @CKM I'm interested to know for any size. If that makes the question too broad, then let's say 6 digits or less.

Comment: You find out your 'friend' is a scammer, and once you transfer money out of your account, the original transfer is cancelled and suddenly you have a big negative balance.  Has Bob ever actually met Alice in person?

Comment: @Shawaron Thanks for the warning.  Alice and Bob know each other well (and can place money in escrow accounts etc. if needs be). Let's ignore the scam possibility.

Comment: I think Franck is asking more about money laundering regulations not about whether or not something is a scam.  I do this kind of thing all the time for friends.  Friend doesn't have cash so I hand a $20 to cover a valet and friend sends me $20 via venmo or some such, obviously a de minimis amount of money but nonetheless.  But the heart of this question is anti-money laundering regulations.

Comment: @quid Correct, hitting some money laundering regulations is indeed one of my concerns.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I know if I was Bob and Alice is my girlfriend, I'd do this without any hesitation.  Barring a relationship that close, I would say Alice's banking fees are her problem and wouldn't get involved regardless of any regulations in place.

Comment: In the US, a conversion of ≈$1,000 on it's own from foreign to USD constitutes a transaction regulated by anti-money laundering compliance, which amounts to essentially a lot of information gathering. At $10K the IRS is involved (currency transaction report, etc.). Then you have banking fees and I have no idea the French regulations.

Comment: Also keep in mind that banks can monitor for structured settlements, such as multiple transfers over a 30-day period that add up to a substantial reporting threshold. And no one publishes their thresholds so people can't skirt them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Alice and Bob are US tax residents, the obvious question is whether Alice made a *gift* to Bob when she transferred the money to Bob, and Bob made a *gift* to Alice when he returned the money, and if so, is the amount large enough that *gift-tax* returns might be required to be filed. No gift tax might need to be *paid* if both parties choose to charge the amount to their lifetime combined estate and gift tax exemptions (currently $5.4M or so), but with transactions of six-digit amounts (anywhere from $100K to nearly $1M) as mentioned by the OP, these reductions can soon deplete the exclusion, especially if repeated at frequent intervals.

If the money is regarded as a *loan* from Alice to Bob that is being repaid in the US, it is best to have documentation to say this is a loan with interest at rates at least as large as the minimum specified by the IRS, and even if the loan document insists that the loan is at zero interest, Alice still has *imputed* income (as if she *did* get interest from Bob at the IRS-specified minimum rate) that she must declare on her income tax return.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, are loan and gift the only 2 options to view the transaction, assuming that Alice and Bob are US tax residents?